# What is the difference between the current and the electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

We know that a changing **electric field** generates a **magnetic field** and that a changing **magnetic field** generates an **electric field**. But does a **magnetic field** generate a **current** ?

We also know that a **charge** generates an **electric field**.

Comment: The first sentence isn't true as written.

Comment: Current is the motion of charges due to whatever force, usially an electric field

Comment: but charges generate an electric field so they generate their own "motor" ?

Answer (score 1):

A changing electric field generates a magnetic field and a changing magnetic field generates an electric field. A current generates a magnetic field, but not the other way round.

Comment: Ok so the difference between an electric field and a current is ?

Comment: Current is movement of charge. Electric field is an association between points in space and vectors that tells you what force would be experienced by a charge (independent of whether there's actually any charge present) .

Comment: @Haatox, it's really an *electromagnetic* field which can support electromagnetic waves that propagate with speed *c* in *vacuum* (no electric charge moving or otherwise present).  Electric current is the flow of electric charge and electric charge is a *property* of an object, e.g., an electron, and not an object itself.

Comment: "A current generates a magnetic field, but not the other way round." A magnetic field does induce a current.

Comment: @BradS, Changing magnetic field produces current, not just magnetic field.

Comment: whoops, that's what I meant.  I meant to say a changing magnetic field induces a current from the electric field it generates.